# Passing button's 'this' in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So to add a function to a button we normally do something like this

```
<button onClick={this.delete_this.bind(this)}>clickable</button>
```

But what if I want to pass the button's 'this' as well, so then I can use it to delete itself in a filter function.

For example:

```
function delete_this(button)
    //button_array defined elsewhere
    return button_array.filter( (item) => item != button);
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: @AndrewLi okay I'll try that, if it's that simple, then I might be overthinking things ><

Comment: @AndrewLi I don't think it's working my button is `<button onClick={this.delete_this.bind(this, this)} value={"hi"}>delete</button>` and i'm running `delete_this(value) { console.log(value.value); } ` and it's coming up with undefined in console.

Comment: @AndrewLi So I should add something like `ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}` to the button itself? So something like: `<button onClick={this.delete_this.bind(this)} ref={ (input) => { this.button = input } }>clickable</button>` ?

Comment: @Solo Okay, that seems to work. I'll try it out with filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use `bind` in `render`, it's not good for performance and it will fail `shouldComponentUpdate` in most cases. Do it in `class` `constructor` instead.

```
<button onClick={this.delete_this}>clickable</button>
```

Now you can use:

- `this` to access the component
- `event.target` to access the button

---

```
function delete_this(event) {
    // event has all kinds of cool stuff, check it out
    console.log(event)

    // current React component (class)
    console.log(this)
}
```

Comment: Would you know how to use it with filter? I'm trying `this.buttons = this.buttons.filter((item) => item != e.target);` but it still has 2 buttons (array contains 2). The arrays are made of `<button ... />`

Comment: If you have a fixed number of buttons (_a'la_ not dynamic), have a look at [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: It's going to be dynamic, which is why I wanted to get the button object, but it's not functioning as I thought it would. It's also what Andrew suggested to me but it returned undefined when I use it.

Comment: It really should return the filtered array, but I'll write a new question instead, since it's not really related to this question.